# Creating Python code with ArcMap to export maps in jpg?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, error-999999

I want to export maps that I have created on ArcMap 10.1 with this Python code:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1): 
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i 
    row = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow
    print row.getValue("no lot")
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"p:\Isa\2018_CS_Bilans_Hydriques_COPIE\CS images cadastre 1\_" + str(row.getValue("no lot")) + ".jpg") 
del mxd
```

The map is saved as JPEG, in a specific folder. I've tried this code before and it worked. I just changed the folder's name in the code and tried to export other maps from the same project and it won't work: it just produces an error code:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 1011, in getValue 
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.GetVa1ue(*gp_fixargs(args))) 
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try writing your JPGs to a folder with a simple path and no spaces in it like `C:\temp` as a test?

Answer (score -1):

Not really an answer...I had a similar experience about a year ago.  The export process, for some unknown reason, started throwing some error that I could never figure out.  My first work around, to switch to a different export format worked for a short while until the same mysterious error was thrown.  The frustration of it all forced me to use ArcGIS Pro and I never saw the error again.  Perhaps that is an option for you?